# Magento 2 sample data won't install

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I use:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

And while its working it finishes with "Killed"

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server did  not have enough memory for composer and process was killed by OOM killer. Please enable swap with 2GB memory at list and rerun command.

Comment: Ubuntu enable swap https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04 helped me enable a 2GB swap file